# how to construct json object using java

Tags: java, json

```
{  
    "lastRanDate":"2018-08-12",
    "statusCode":"200",
    "errorCode":null,
    "statusCodeShortDesc":null,
    "statusMessage":null,
    "programs":[  
        {  
            "name":"program1",
            "programData":{  
                "SNCount":"5000",
                "progAggregate":{  
                    "percentage":"90%",
                    "severity":"medium"
                },
                "sites":[  
                    {  
                        "name":"FXZZ",
                        "siteData":{  
                            "siteAggregate":{  
                                "percentage":"90%",
                                "severity":"medium"
                            },
                            "dates":[  
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {  
                                    "date":"24 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "name":"FXZZ",
                        "siteData":{  
                            "siteAggregate":{  
                                "percentage":"90%",
                                "severity":"medium"
                            },
                            "dates":[  
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {  
            "name":"program2",
            "programData":{  
                "SNCount":"5000",
                "progAggregate":{  
                    "percentage":"90%",
                    "severity":"medium"
                },
                "sites":[  
                    {  
                        "name":"FXZZ",
                        "siteData":{  
                            "siteAggregate":{  
                                "percentage":"90%",
                                "severity":"medium"
                            },
                            "dates":[  
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {  
                        "name":"FXZZ",
                        "siteData":{  
                            "siteAggregate":{  
                                "percentage":"90%",
                                "severity":"medium"
                            },
                            "dates":[  
                                {  
                                    "date":"23 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {  
                                    "date":"24 May",
                                    "dateAggregate":"90%",
                                    "dateData":[  
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table1",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table2",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table3",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table4",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table5",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        },
                                        {  
                                            "name":"table6",
                                            "value":"90%"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting this as `json` response I have to construct this response in java and passed to rest `api` i am new to `json` please help me

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Jackson, here's a nice tutorial for you to follow: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have any inbuilt methods for parsing and storing JSON objects. You can use third party library GSON or JSONParser from Google to process JSON in Java.

1. Download and Configure [SimpleJson](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) from Google .
2. Import the Downloaded Package.
3. Then use following code to parse JSON:

   JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

   JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);

json is your JSON object.